# How safe is traveling from Texas to Mexico by bus?

Tags: usa, safety, buses, mexico, texas

Given recent violent, drug-war-related crime along the USA/Mexico border, what are the risks of traveling from USA to Texas by intercity bus? Have there been incidents involving international buses in the recent past? Are there cities or routes that are lower risk to travel via than others?

I was thinking of traveling from Dallas to Monterrey.

Comment: The drug wars usually are not targeted at tourists, unless they are caught up in the middle, but in general you'll be safe at least from the drug war thing..

Comment: Sure, what about risk of mugging/getting held-up or kidnapping? Are any bus lines known to be involved in smuggling?

Comment: I've since found this article that seems to say my concerns were not totally unfounded. The key seems to be where you're traveling. Even where it's bad the overall the risk is not that major, in relativity to things like getting killed in a car crash http://www.insightcrime.org/news-analysis/going-to-the-border-in-tamaulipas-mexico-get-a-police-escort

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most tourists are not even looked at for this kind of thing as they have no value to the drug cartels.

As always, you just have to be mindful and be safe.

For taking the bus, one thing to consider is have a few peso coins handing for the restroom along the way. Also, take some toilet paper with you.

As far as smuggling, border control is pretty tight, and getting through with anything smuggled is going to be quite difficult. Most of that stuff happens out in the desert anyway.

Enjoy the bus ride, Dallas to Monterrey sounds like a great trip to take.

Answer (score 2):

My limited experience with Mexican buses (not in an area heavily affected by the drug war) was that it did feel dangerous to me sometimes. But that was simply because in order to get to and from bus stops, or to change buses, I sometimes had to cross freeway overpasses or make my way through heavy traffic.

Answer (score 2):

Actually i live in Reynosa,Tamaulipas (border with Hidalgo,Texas), and actually travel to monterrey the last month, and i will tell you something, mexico its not like you see on the news, i don't know how to explain, but yea its a war right now, but

there is currently a drug war in Mexico, that's something we all know but let me put a example, I have a girlfriend who lives in Rio Bravo Tamaulipas border with Donna, Texas, and every day I travel 25 min to his city (currently taking 20 minutes of road and me never happened).

There are some people who have thought about the current situation in Mexico, but let me tell you if you're a quiet person, normally transitas around town and your visit to Mexico is quiet, it is very unlikely that something happens to you.

Another example could be my dad is now a physician authorized representative, that means having to travel 15 days throughout Tamaulipas (currently one of the most dangerous states), and thankfully never had problems, also a friend of mine just told me visit ago 1 day (December 29), came from Mexico to Reynosa and all good without any problem

I think the only problem is you came on your truck or car knowing that in the US most luxurious cars in mexico, that would be a problem if used as the drugdealers really like luxury cars and you could draw your attention, but considering that come by bus, not think there is any risk by coming to the border

Hope you have a good trip

Comment: Thanks, I understand I'm not likely to be affected by violent crimes, but there is some heightened risk. I'm asking specifically about any issues with buses.

Comment: there is not risk, some friend mine travel each 15 days form reynosa to monterrey just to watch Tigres team (locally futboll soccer team), and has been doing this for years, so there is no problem